# Patching Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a set of patch files which was used to patch the Linux 2.6.29 kernel for supporting my custom functionality.

I would like to know if it is possible to use the same patch files to patch my new kernel (linux 2.6.32) for getting the same functionality.

Thanks & Regards,
Sen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patch is *always* dependent on the kernel version. How well the patch applies depends on how different the version which it was made for vs. the version it was applied to is. In the best case.

There will be four possibilites:

1. Neither the file, data structures, or APIs have changed, and the files will just cleanly apply.
2. The data structures and APIs have not changed, but there were minor changes to the file *outside* of your patched area. So, patch will work, and give you minor errors indicating the lines were shifted a bit.
3. Some of the code inside the patched area changed, so the patch will not apply. You will have to manually figure out what these differences are, and possibly apply that section of the patch manually to get it to apply. Patch will fail, and will save a ".rej" file showing the rejected section.
4. Functional changes have been made to the code, data structures, or APIs have changed. So you will not be able to port the patches without figuring out how the underlying code has changed, and modifying the patches to apply to the new paradigm. Of course, you might not know this is the case, and you may have a patch that applies just fine, but then the kernel crashes - so beware! ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to revert to the original file after the patch has been applied??

Comment: If it were a straight patch, you can pass the "reverse" flag "-R" to back the patch out. I'd advise passing the "-b" flag, to make backups.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer here. It heavily depends on the contents of the patch and the code that it touches. If it's the addition of a new module, it'll probably. Get both versions of the kernel and diff the relevant code pieces to see if they have changed much. If your patch is for a piece that haven't changed, you're in luck.

Comment: If you apply the patch manually, it will just tell you if it was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can apply your patches with a new Linux version. At least you can (and should!) try to do so. If you're lucky it works... But it really depends on the patches and how version dependend they are.

Philip

Comment: Are patches version dependent?

Comment: @Sen - Philip said it depends on how dependent the patch is on the version of the kernel.

Comment: Right... If you did not develop the code behind the patch you cannot tell. Therefore you need to test it. (Or ask on the patch's mailinglist...)